Does saving the language preference of the user in a cookie require a cookie banner?
Websites like https://gdpr.eu/cookies categorize the language preference of the user as "preferences cookies" (aka "functionality cookies"). As far as I understand, the user has to provide consent before a website is allowed to set such a cookie, is this correct?

I'd say that usage comes under the following exemption given by the ICO

the cookie is strictly necessary to provide an ‘information society
service’ (eg a service over the internet) requested by the subscriber
or user. Note that it must be essential to fulfil their request –
cookies that are helpful or convenient but not essential, or that are
only essential for your own purposes, will still require consent.

If you opt out of cookies, but switch the language to Welsh, the ICO's own website set a language cookie.
I do not believe the law is different in the UK, so I trust the ICO as a source of truth on the cookie law.
Still list it on your cookies page, though.

Thanks for the quick response! The "Further reading" box on the page you've linked to in fact links to a document that contains specific guidelines for my use case (see section 3.6 "UI customization cookies" of https://ec.europa.eu/justice/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2012/wp194_en.pdf)
The key takeaways are:

Remembering a language choice in a cookie is ok, as long as an explicit action lead to a language change
The expiration must be "short term" (no longer than a few hours after a browsing session has ended). An additional note can be used to expand this.


It's still interesting to me though that the ICO website saves the language cookie with the expiration set to a week. Anyway, that document seems to be really clear, I think that is what should be complied with.
